# How to get collection of subelements at specific index in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have sample DOM:

```
<div class="x">
  <div class="y">
    <span>a</span>
    <span>b</span>
    <span>c</span>
  </div>
  <div class="y">
    <span>d</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>f</span>
  </div>  
</div>
```

The jquery expression `$(".x .y span")` returns all 6 span elements (a,b,c,d,e,f). The expression `$(".x .y span:eq(1)")` returns only one span element - b.

How should look expression returning collection of subelements at specific index, for exmaple at index 1 (b,e).

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
$(".x .y span:nth-child(2)")
```

Answer (score 0):

e is not in the .y selector ! 
fix that before